# Why is there a difference between df.info() and df.dtypes.memory_usage(deep=True) results?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory, in-memory

I am trying to do a pd.merge on two rather large datasets with shapes ~ A - (24482319, 33) and B - (12029240, 165). This is throwing memory errors though I have a 32 RAM, Core-i9, Dell XPS with 2TB SSD, pandas in-memory operations. After optimizing the data types, I tried to check what the respective sizes (using df.info()) and memory usage (df.dtypes.memory_usage(deep=True)) of the datasets are. The results are as follows:

| df | Size | Memory Usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3.1+ GB | 6,531 |
| B | 6.0+ GB | 34,154 |

Detailed info are as below:

```
**A.info()**
-----------
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 24482319 entries, 0 to 24482318
Columns: 33 entries, MSISDN to GSM_DECILE
dtypes: category(9), datetime64[ns](3), float32(19), float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 3.1+ GB

**B.info()**
-----------
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 12029240 entries, 0 to 12029239
Columns: 165 entries, MSISDN to MFS_DECILE
dtypes: category(6), datetime64[ns](4), float32(103), int16(25), int8(26), object(1)
memory usage: 6.0+ GB
```

I believe that dataframe B is the culprit here (i.e. causing the in-memory operation, pd.merge, to fail) so my question is this: Why is the memory usage of B nearly 6x of its side when A is just ~2x its size? How can I reduce the memory usage?

Thank you

Comment: What is the exact output of `memory_usage(deep=True)`... that should be a series...

Comment: "Why is the memory usage of B nearly 6x of its side when A is just ~2x its size?" It's hard to say without more information. note using `object` dtype usually means you've created a bunch of Python `str` objects, which is not memory efficient. If you want to us to be able to help you are going to have to provide much more information, we can only speculate otherwise

Comment: What do you mean by "size" here... `df.size` does not give you anything in terms of bytes, its just a number.

Comment: Thanks for your response @juanpa.arrivillaga.

The exact output of memory_usage(deep=True) for each of the dataframes is what I displayed in the table above as memory usage.

Size is obtained from running df.info() see specific outputs for each table (as well as column data types) in my initial post (under the table).

Also, not that I have just one object column in each of the dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you use `info()` ***without deep memory usage***. Try `df.info(memory_usage='deep')` to get the same size. Without deep parameter it counts memory based only on datatypes, not data.